# Webscraping Covers.com

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am struggling to find where the data is contained when I inspect the webpage. I have the following code where the html_node argument does not have the correct entry

```
library(rvest)

url <- paste0("https://www.covers.com/sport/basketball/nba/teams/main/boston-celtics/2022-2023") 

covers <- url %>% read_html %>% html_node('#div_schedule') %>% html_table()
```

I have tried all of the following #div_tab_content, #div_past_results, #div_tp_schedule`

These do not work, and I can't see any more IDs. When I inspect the webpage, I get the following error

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : no applicable method for
'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html_table()` on the entire HTML content and it will extract all tables it can find in a list.

```r
library(rvest)

url <-
  paste0(
    "https://www.covers.com/sport/basketball/nba/teams/main/boston-celtics/2022-2023"
  )

covers_tables <-
  url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()

covers_tables
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 21 × 5
#>    Playoffs Playoffs Playoffs  Playoffs Playoffs
#>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
#>  1 Date     VS       Score     ATS      O/U     
#>  2 May 29   MIA      L 84-103  L -7.5   U 204   
#>  3 May 27   @ MIA    W 104-103 L -2     U 209   
#>  4 May 25   MIA      W 110-97  W -8.5   U 214.5 
#>  5 May 23   @ MIA    W 116-99  W 1      U 216   
#>  6 May 21   @ MIA    L 102-128 L -4.5   O 214   
#>  7 May 19   MIA      L 105-111 L -10    O 214.5 
#>  8 May 17   MIA      L 116-123 L -8.5   O 212   
#>  9 May 14   PHI      W 112-88  W -6     U 202.5 
#> 10 May 11   @ PHI    W 95-86   W -2.5   U 211   
#> # ℹ 11 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 83 × 5
#>    `Regular Season` `Regular Season` `Regular Season` `Regular Season`
#>    <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#>  1 Date             VS               Score            ATS             
#>  2 Apr 9            ATL              W 120-114        W -4.5          
#>  3 Apr 7            TOR              W 121-102        W 1.5           
#>  4 Apr 5            TOR              W 97-93          W 2             
#>  5 Apr 4            @ PHI            L 101-103        W 3.5           
#>  6 Mar 31           UTA              W 122-114        L -13           
#>  7 Mar 30           @ MIL            W 140-99         W 2             
#>  8 Mar 28           @ WAS            L 111-130        L -10.5         
#>  9 Mar 26           SA               W 137-93         W -16.5         
#> 10 Mar 24           IND              W 120-95         W -11           
#> # ℹ 73 more rows
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: `Regular Season` <chr>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   `Pre Season` `Pre Season`               `Pre Season` `Pre Season` `Pre Season`
#>   <chr>        <chr>                      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 Date         "VS"                       Score        ATS          O/U         
#> 2 Oct 14       "@ TOR\n            \n   … L 134-137 (… L -5         O 219       
#> 3 Oct 7        "@ CHA\n            \n   … W 112-103    W -4.5       U 216       
#> 4 Oct 5        "TOR"                      L 119-125 (… L -4         O 220.5     
#> 5 Oct 2        "CHA"                      W 134-93     W -6         O 214.5     
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 0 × 4
#> # ℹ 4 variables: Rank <lgl>, Leader <lgl>, L10 <lgl>, Units <lgl>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I am beginning my journey with webscraping in R, are there any resources that you would recommend to help me learn? Ideally I would post my questions here but I do not want to waste people's time with my novice questions

Comment: The [rvest package homepage](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/rvest.html) has a few articles that might help. I recommend trying out different things and playing with the code, observing what happens in each step.